# How to I resolve this error after trying to install mysql on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I am getting the following error when trying to install mysql-server on Ubuntu 12.04

```
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-libuser linux-headers-3.2.0-27 libqtwebkit4 python-central libuser1 linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 125 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/8,737 kB of archives.
After this operation, 31.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 312756 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This seems like a bug on the package, possibly due to a particular condition on your system that makes mysql fail to start properly. Please, run this on a terminal to help debug the problem: `sudo bash -x /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Answer (score 0):

In your datadir usually /var/lib/mysql there should be a file .err where you can find more details. Please have a look into that file. First you will see a lot of start messages and information about MySQL configuring its datadir. The problem starts when you come across an error or fatal message line. If you are unclear about the meaning please post the rest of the file.